# Smack's FileTransferManager.createOutgoingFileTransfer only accepts full JIDs. How can I determine the full JID of a user in Smack?

Tags: xmpp, file-transfer, smack, asmack

After hours of debugging and trying to find out why the file transfer was not working using aSmack, while normal messaging was, I finally managed to pin it down to this.

The Openfire server is sending the Rosters' JID missing the / at the end when I follow the method given in the Smack documentation to get a user's Roster list.

```
Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
for (RosterEntry r : entries) {
    Log.v("Gabriel","Receiving: " + r.getUser());
}
```

For example if I receive a message from the user gabriel, I get the "From" as:

```
gabriel@dragonov/Smack
```

But the r.getUser() returns to the user as

```
gabriel@dragonov
```

Even

```
connection.getRoster().getPresence(contactName).getFrom()
```

is returning is as "gabriel@dragonov".

This is causing the File transfer to fail, but oddly not the regular messaging. However when I manually add the /Smack at the end of

```
 OutgoingFileTransfer transferr = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(contactJID+"/Smack");
```

it works.

My question is, how can I receive the full JID with the resource part included or configure the file transfer so that it doesn't fail when using a bare JID?

---

Edit:

I have tried the following method:

```
 Log.v("Gabriel", entries.size() + " buddy(ies):");
    for (RosterEntry r : entries) {
        Log.v("Pat","adding: " + r.getType() + "  " + r.getName());
        contacts.add(r.getUser());
    }      

    for (String contact : contacts){
        Iterator<org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence> presences = connection.getRoster().getPresences(contact);
        Log.v("Gabriel", contact+" has: ");
        while(presences.hasNext()){
            Log.v("Gabriel",presences.next().getFrom());
        }           
    }
```

But I am still getting the bare ID.

The output:
    gabriel@dragonov has: 
    gabriel@dragonov

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Iterator<Presence> Roster.getPresences(String user)`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.2.2/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/Roster.html#getPresences%28java.lang.String%29) to get the presence information from all known resources of a user. For this Presence instances `getFrom()` should return a full JID which you can use in `FileTransferManager.createOutgoingFileTransfer()`.

I have created [SMACK-430](http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-430), regarding the use of a full JID in `createOutgoingFileTranfer()`. It really should throw an exception so that smack users don't have to debug hours to find the reason (although it's stated in the method javadoc). SMACK-430 also explains why FileTransferManager needs a full JID and can not be used with a bare JID.

Comment: My bad. I thought I mentioned somewhere that I was using asmack, but it seems I didn't. Roster.getPresences is not an available method there it seems :(

Comment: Ah nevermind. I found it's in the connection.getRoster(). I have tried as you said, but I am still getting the bare JID. Please check my question above, I edited it.

Comment: You should update your aSmack version, if you are using an old one. aSmack definitely has `Roster.getPresences()`.

Comment: That version should have `getPresences()`

Comment: Weird. The only two static methods that Roster has is Roster.getDefaultSubscriptionMode() and   Roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(subscriptionMode)

Comment: That's because it's not an static method (see [Roster javadoc](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.2.2/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/Roster.html)) :)

Comment: Oh alright. I assumed it was static because of Roster. The instantiated roster I am using is the one I got from connection.getRoster() which has getPresences, but that one is returning bare JIDs and not full ones. Is there another roster I need to use?

Comment: No there is no other user. The presences returned by getPresences() should have a full JID as 'from' value.

Comment: I know it's weird, but I'm getting the bare JID when using the roster.. Here is the response: RCV  (1079466960): <iq type="result" id="hbQl7-2" to="gabriel@dragonov/Smack"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"><item jid="ralph@dragonov" name="ralph" subscription="none"/></query></iq>. I manually added the users to the roster, and the user accounts, could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Mr.Flow can I have a chat with you please someway?

Comment: Sure, Chat contact information is mentioned in Smack's Readme.