# asmack-android-8-4.0.5.jar createOutgoingFileTransfer need fullJID I can't get it

Tags: smack, asmack

1.I had read https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions /filetransfer.html
**snippet code from this  guide， it not need resource part**

```
// Create the file transfer manager
   FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(connection);
// Create the outgoing file transfer
   OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer("romeo@montague.net");
// Send the file
   transfer.sendFile(new File("shakespeare_complete_works.txt"), "You won't believe this!");
```

2.so I read spark source code org.jivesoftware.spark.PresenceManager find this method , so the documentation long time no to update;

```
/**
 * Returns the fully qualified jid of a user.
 *
 * @param jid the users bare jid (ex. derek@jivesoftware.com)
 * @return the fully qualified jid of a user (ex. derek@jivesoftware.com --> derek@jivesoftware.com/spark)
 */
public static String getFullyQualifiedJID(String jid) {
System.out.println("getFullyQualifiedJID : " + jid);
    final Roster roster = SparkManager.getConnection().getRoster();
    Presence presence = roster.getPresence(jid);
    System.out.println("getFullyQualifiedJID : " + presence.getFrom());
    return presence.getFrom();
}
```

3. I find this method not work for asmack , so google it found this
   [Smack's FileTransferManager.createOutgoingFileTransfer only accepts full JIDs. How can I determine the full JID of a user in Smack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518440/smacks-filetransfermanager-createoutgoingfiletransfer-only-accepts-full-jids-h)

   //snippet code from my project
   Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
   List presenceList = roster.getPresences(jid);
   Log.d(TAG, "bareJid : " + jid);
   for (Presence presence : presenceList) {
       Log.d(TAG, "fullJID : " + presence.getFrom());
   }

why the code can not get the fullJID.
the output：

12-23 06:55:35.840: D/MChat(1805): bareJid : test@tigereye-pc
12-23 06:55:35.840: D/MChat(1805): fullJID : test@tigereye-pc

4.the result is the same, so how can I get the fullJID
Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

The need the full JID and the client *resource*.

You can do something like that:

```
String fullJID = xmppConnection.getRoster().getPresence(JID).getFrom();
```

My JID variable is the full JID without the **resource**.

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply Full user id as : user@serveripaddress/Smack

For Example :
             xyz@192.168.1.1/Smack